# Using regex replace while typing into input field

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got this regex:

```
(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{2})/g;
```

What I want to do is to replace every 2, when every 3 and when every 2 again character with a " " while typing. Which means if I type "123" it should be formatted to "12 3" and if I type "12345" it should be formatted to "12 123 "

However I get a spacing only after every 7 character.
Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K4WXc/257/

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What should be output for `123456` and `1234567`, `123465789`?

Comment: Try [`return v.replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+$)|^\d(?=\d{2}$)/g, "$& ");`](http://jsfiddle.net/xsy4femz/) and let know if that meets your requirements.

Comment: @Tushar 'the pattern is "xx xxx xx" so if I type 123456 it should look "12 345 6" in the input. If I type 1234567 it should be "12 345 67 " and for 123465789 it should be "12 346 57" (i'll update my jsfiddle with a maxlength property of 7 so it won't be possible to type a longer string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your help!  if I type "111" it becomes "1 11" and it should be "11 1". It becomes correct when I type 5 numbers though -  "11 111". But for six numbers it becomes "111 111" when it should be "11 111 1"

Comment: Try [`v.replace(/^(\d{2}) ?(\d{3})?(?=\d)/g, "$1 $2 ");`](http://jsfiddle.net/xsy4femz/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K4WXc/261/) as shown below:

```
    return v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{1,3})(\d{0,2}).*/, function (match, a, b, c) {
        return a + ' ' + b + (c == '' ? '' : ' ' + c);
    });
```

Keeping in mind that just before this block, you have removed any non-digits, this block expects just digits (no spaces).

It matches 2 digits at the beginning: `^(\d{2})`

Then 1 to 3 as the next capture group: `(\d{1,3})`

If there are 3 in that 2nd group, it will capture up to 2 more: `(\d{0,2})`

Anything more than that will be discarded: `.*`

The important part of this that enables it to match "incomplete" entries as you type is that it matches even if you haven't typed all 3 digits of the 2nd group, or both of the 3rd group.

**NOTE:** the main problem with your original replace was the missing first param that represents the whole matched string.

Comment: I modified the code to accept a data parameter for the input filter: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/K4WXc/263/